# Display emoji/emotion icon in Android TextView

Tags: java, android, unicode, textview, emoji

I have some problem with displaying emoji icon in Android TextView

First, I found a list of emoji icon in unicode at here:
http://www.easyapns.com/category/just-for-fun

Second, I found how to display emoji icon at here:
https://github.com/sharakova/EmojiTextView/blob/master/src/jp/sharakova/android/emoji/EmojiTextView.java

The EmojiTextView.java can convert the predefined character to emoji icon automatically. Therefore, I want to replace all the occurrences of emoji icon in a String to some predefined character, and put the result to EmojiTextView.java
The problem is my code cannot recognize emoji icon in the String which contains emoji icon.

Here is my code snippet - I am trying to find if the input match any unicode of emoji icon:

```
// Array list of all emoji icon
private static final String[] ArrayEUnicodeString ={
    "\uE415",
    "\uE056",
    "\uE057",
    ...
}

// Nothing matched when it receive emoji icon with unicode "\uE415" from iphone. 'input' is message received from XMPP server
for (int i=0; i < emojiLength; i++)
{

    if (input.getBytes() == ArrayEUnicodeString[i].getBytes())
        Log.e("test", "ArrayEUnicodeString found");
}
// Note: iphone can display the emoji icon if I send "\uE415"
```

I am not good at unicode comparison/convention. Can somebody help me please, thanks!

Comment: If you are planning on embedding the iPhone emoji graphics in your app, be aware that this is a violation of copyright. It wouldn't surprise me if you got away with it (the Android marketplace is full of apps which violate copyright), but you should be aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Anyway, do you know how to compare the input String and the String[] ArrayEUnicodeString?

Comment: @mobileappBeginner r u able to show \ue415 in android ?

Comment: No, Android cannot show \ue415

Comment: Hi. I too want to transfer the emoticons from andriod to android and to i phone also. do u succeded in emoticons transferring using xmpp. how you implemented for sending and receiving. i mean how you are detecting the text that has emoticon in between the text? i am using smack api for android. do i need to implement the :) or unicode in android ? Please let me know about the implementation.@mobile app Beginner

Comment: @mobile app Beginner:-Can you please share your code with here. I am still facing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try to find the emoji using a regular expression: "[\ue415\ue056\ue057]", instead of comparing the bytes.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you want to embed the protected Apple emoji images in your application at all?

The Unicode standard includes 722 emoji that can be displayed by Android's default font just by entering the Unicode chars into an `EditText` field or `TextView`.

You can, in addition, use the following library (in folder "Java") to automatically convert popular emoticons like `:-)` to the corresponding Unicode emoji:

https://github.com/delight-im/Emoji

Comment: The Unicode character set is a standard and all companies will draw each unicode character the way they want. The same smiley face will look different on *all* devices, not the same on all devices *except* Apple.

The problem I'm still having with Android Studio and Emoji's is that I have to execute many lines of code just to include "". I tried: textView.text = "", but it didn't work. Yeeeeesh, how hard can it be?

Answer (score 6):

**Here, Please go through below solution :**

**Problem :** Inside TextView instead of Emoji, String **\ue415\ue056\ue057** is showing.

**Root cause :** In java or android, programmatically string representation of Emoji's you will get as **\\ue415\\ue056\\ue057**. But when you try to print same String in console or LogCat then escape character is removed and you will get string as **\ue415\ue056\ue057** because of which root cause of this issue is not detectable.

**Solution :** To solve this issue, we need to handle escape character. I have created below method which solve this problem.

```
public static String getEmojiFromString(String emojiString) {

    if (!emojiString.contains("\\u")) {

        return emojiString;
    }
    String emojiEncodedString = "";

    int position = emojiString.indexOf("\\u");

    while (position != -1) {

        if (position != 0) {
            emojiEncodedString += emojiString.substring(0, position);
        }

        String token = emojiString.substring(position + 2, position + 6);
        emojiString = emojiString.substring(position + 6);
        emojiEncodedString += (char) Integer.parseInt(token, 16);
        position = emojiString.indexOf("\\u");
    }
    emojiEncodedString += emojiString;

    return emojiEncodedString;
}
```

Comment: simple and great answer.

Answer (score 4):

It works fine if you convert the string to a char array and check each char, such as:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char curr : str.toCharArray()) {
    sb.append((SUPPORTED_EMOJI_SET.contains(curr)) ? convertCharToImgTag(curr) : curr);
}
```

where SUPPORTED_EMOJI_SET is just a set of chars, for example:

```
new HashSet<Character>() {{
    add('\ue415');
    add('\ue056');
    ...
}}
```

You could also do this with a regex but I believe the above would run faster.

Comment: @esilver could you please guide me how could I use emoji icons in my android app without violation any copyright.