# How to render emoji in a Textview in android?

Tags: android, chat, render, emoji

I am working on a chat application where i am implementing emoji but i have one question in adapter how to render the emoji in a Textview.

```
emocationGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            emoDrawables.get(position).setBounds(0, 0, emoDrawables.get(position).getIntrinsicWidth(),
            emoDrawables.get(position).getIntrinsicHeight());

            int selectionCursor = chatMsgEtd.getSelectionStart();
            chatMsgEtd.getText().insert(selectionCursor, ".");
            selectionCursor = chatMsgEtd.getSelectionStart();

            SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(chatMsgEtd.getText());
            builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(emoDrawables.get(position)), selectionCursor - ".".length(),
                    selectionCursor, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            chatMsgEtd.setText(builder);
            chatMsgEtd.setSelection(selectionCursor);
        }
});
```

Adapter

```
chatMsgTxt.setText(chats.get(position).getMessage());
```

So in the adapter the getMessage is the chat message but here how to render the emoji with message.

Please go through my post and suggest me some solution.

Comment: is your emoji is custom or android default one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display emoji/emotion icon in Android TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740565/display-emoji-emotion-icon-in-android-textview)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes emoji is my custom implementation no android default one.

Comment: @cricket_007 is there any unicode values are there for emoji.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You want a [table](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)?

Comment: @cricket_007 i am asking about this table http://www.easyapns.com/category/just-for-fun

Comment: Okay, there are unicode values for emoji. What is your question?

Comment: @cricket_007 how to render this one, String msg = "\ue415" + " hello";
        chatMsgTxt.setText(msg);

Comment: Sorry, should've marked this as the duplicate post. I just picked one with the most votes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893796/how-set-emoji-by-unicode-in-android-textview

Answer (score 0):

You can set a span on your `TextView`, most likely you want to extend `DynamicDrawableSpan` and source the images into the span. If your goal is to render iOS emojis instead of the default android ones you should use a library like https://github.com/instachat/emoji-library or https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon